# Clojure - substring? function

Tags: strings, clojure

Trying to write a substring function in Clojure. I am sure there is a more idiomatic way. Can anyone enlighten me?

Otherwise, here is my version. Thoughts?

```
(defn substring? 
  "is 'sub' in 'str'?"
  [sub str] 
  (if (not= (.indexOf str sub) -1) 
    true 
    false))
```

Comment: hmmm...just discovered - (.contains "abcdefghi" "abc"), anyway that doesn't interop with Java (purely out of curiosity!)?

Comment: a `re-find` might be the simplest way. The old `contrib.string` used `.contains` as well so it was probably the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you wrote in your comments, (.contains "str" "sub") is perfectly fine. it is indeed java interop - it runs the method contains on String object "str".

two more comments, first, passing str as a var name isnt so good, since str is a function, so you should consider giving it a different name. Second, in your implementation, its quite redundant to write

```
(defn substring? [sub st]
  (if (not= (.indexOf st sub) -1) 
   true 
   false))
```

You could simply write

```
(defn substring? [sub st]
 (not= (.indexOf st sub) -1))
```